# Zend Framework 1.12. Is it possible to define object inside function init() and use it as global object

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpstorm

I cannot use autocomplete if I call an object inside function `init()` like this:

```
class IndexController extends HiNStudio_Controller {

private $model_obj;

public function init() {
    $this -> model_obj = new Default_Model_Account();
}

public function indexAction() {
    $this -> model_obj ->  //(it should be something autocomplete here)
}
```

[image: pic]

The code is still working if I call correct function name. Ex:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this -> model_obj ->  checkLogin();
}
```

Is there any case to display autocomplete function instead of call Object inside each function like this:

```
class IndexController extends HiNStudio_Controller {

private $model_obj;

public function init() {

}

public function indexAction() {
    $this -> model_obj = new Default_Model_Account();
    $this -> model_obj ->  //(autocomplete is working here)
}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typehint your variable with PHPDoc comment.

```
/** @var Default_Model_Account */
private $model_obj;
```

PhpStorm looses variable type if it's not initialized in constructor or not used in the same method where initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with PHP but I think it is releated to that at the method call model_obj can be not initialized. Try to replace function init with constructor.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php This would mean that when you create new object of IndexController constructor will always set model_obj variable.